# React Nested Foreach on Return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to use nested foreach in React.
But not working at all;

```
 return (
  {category.map((item, i) => (
   <div className="col-sm-12">
    <h5>{item.title}</h5>
   </div>
   item.data.map((it, iv) => (
    <div class="col-6">
     <ProductCard {...it}  />
    </div>
   ))
  ))}
  )
```

Comment: what does not work? you mean nothing gets rendered?

Comment: `forEach` != `map`. You're using the right one in the code, but you should use consistent language in your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [.map](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjDzcjwioL3AhVaet4KHVPnDHwQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AOvVaw12XNJirv8-3J2POqmbqwb2) higher order function
you need to wrap in in fragment so React Will know that it's  a JSX or wrap it on div

[Introduction to JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

[Learn Fragment React](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
 return (
 <>
  {category.map((item, i) => (
   <div className="col-sm-12">
    <h5>{item.title}</h5>
   </div>
   item.data.map((it, iv) => (
    <div class="col-6">
     <ProductCard {...it}  />
    </div>
   ))
  ))}
 </>
  )
```

Comment: Did you run this? It only addresses one of several issues. The `map` must return a single React element (it doesn't), and the nested map must also be wrapped in JSX of some sort.

Comment: oh it's because the data is empty first you need to wrap it on div try that it will work

Comment: `return (
 <div>
  {category.map((item, i) => (
   <div className="col-sm-12">
    <h5>{item.title}</h5>
   </div>
   item.data.map((it, iv) => (
    <div class="col-6">
     <ProductCard {...it}  />
    </div>
   ))
  ))}
 </div>
  ) `

Answer (score 0):

if you want to render nested array maybe it will work

```
 return (
<> // Put Wrapper
 {category.map((item, i) => (
   <>                                    // put an empty fragment to contain title div and another map 
     <div key={i} className="col-sm-12"> // dont forget to put key props
       <h5>{item.title}</h5>
     </div>
     {item.data.map((it, iv) => (        // wrap another map on '{}' because it inside jsx
       <div key={iv} class="col-6">      // dont forget to put key props
         <ProductCard {...it}  />
       </div>
      )}
   </>
 )}
</>
)
```

you can also change <> to div or any if you want to style it. And dont put // comment on jsx, it just my mark to explain this code